# int i in for loop not changing the address (c language)

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, int

So I'm trying to generate an array of random ints dynamically. The problem is that the same address, j, is added to the array. Could some one shine some light on this? Thanks for your time.

```
#define size 100

int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));

    int *array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 1){
        int j = rand();
        array[i] = &j;
    }

    IntArray_printArray(array, size);
}
```

Output of the print function:

```
Array Contents: [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702],  ... [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702],  ... [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702], [2702]
```

Edit 1: The "IntArray_printArray" function:

```
void IntArray_printArray(int *array, int size){
    printf("Array Contents: ");
    if (size <= 20){
        printf("Array Contents: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i += 1){
            printf("[%d], ", *(int*)array[i]);
        }
        printf("[%d]\n", *(int*)array[size-1]);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 1){
            printf("[%d], ", *(int*)array[i]);
        }
        printf(" ... ");
        for (int i = size/2 - 3; i < size/2 + 3; i += 1){
            printf("[%d], ", *(int*)array[i]);
        }
        printf(" ... ");
        for (int i = size - 6; i < size - 1; i += 1){
            printf("[%d], ", *(int*)array[i]);
        }
        printf("[%d]\n", *(int*)array[size-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems the function IntArray_printArray is the culprit. Post the code of this function for us to be able to tell the issue.

Comment: The compiler should be giving you a warning about this code, as `array[i]` is an `int`, yet you're trying to assign an `int*` to it.  If you're not compiling with warnings enabled, do so.  If you are, don't ignore the warnings.

Comment: What is the value of `size`? Did you initialize it? Otherwise it is possible that `malloc` fails, and then you will get a segmentation fault when you assign to `array[i]` since `array == NULL` if malloc fails.

Comment: yes it is #define at the top. I will add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of `j` is unspecified, but it's not random. while it technically doesn't have to be at the same address in each loop iteration, I;d be surprised if you ever cam across a compiler that didn't put it at the same address.

Another thing to keep in mind is that once the loop is finished, the lifetime of `j` is over.  So the lifetime of whatever address got stored in the `array` elements is over.  It's not valid to dereference those pointers anymore.

So the values printed out by `IntArray_printArray()` may not even reflect any of the random values that you stored in the `j` variable (I'm assuming that `IntArray_printArray()` prints the value pointed to by the pointers in the array, rather than the the values of the pointers themselves).

Comment: This is actually quite a deep answer that deserves careful reading.

Answer (score 1):

The address of `j` does not change because C++ compiler optimizes the creation of the variable `j` and assigns a fixed address(basically on the stack) to it.

Here is what might be happening on assembly language level(pseudo asm):

```
2702 
2698 <- stack_ptr pointing here(32 bit machine)

;new instruction to create `j`
addl stack_ptr, $4 ;j created

2702 <- stack_ptr pointing here now
2698
```

after the `for` block ends, the stack pointer is decremented by 4

```
2702
2698 <- stack_ptr here, after loop block ends, but not that `for` loop itself has ended.
```

and the cycle repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

array[i] = j;

Otherwise you are storing a fixed address of the random numbers.

EDIT: the above works fine for me, added some test code for Chris to check:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    const int size = 10;

    int *array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int j = rand();
        array[i] = j;
        printf("array[%d] = %d \n", i, array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this causes the program to crash.

Comment: How does the program crash? What is the line where it crashes? What is the error?

Comment: I dont know. Im using Eclipse; its just saying "program.exe has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..."

Comment: Hi Chris, it works for me, must be something else in your program that is causing the problem.  See my edit above, I added some test code for you to check, this ran fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

i think even though the address of j's lifetime is just in the loop,but it is a same address in the stack, just like Aniket said.